# UDK - Commercial Use Age Limit

Tags: udk, commercial

So I'm 15 and I was wondering if there is an age limit to be able to publish a commercial-game.
I know that I have to pay $99 to buy a commercial license

Comment: You obviously did not read the user license agreements.

Answer (score 1):

You must at [Age of consent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_consent) so you could get a license personally, [quote](https://www.unrealengine.com/previous-versions/udk-licensing-resources):

> A note to developers under the age of consent (minors): Please have
>   your parent or guardian contact us for a UDK Commercial Use License,
>   as we cannot enter into a license agreement with a minor.